# Inline Python, not able to read stdout/sdterr from python to perl

Tags: python, perl

```
use Test::Trap;
use Data::Dumper;

use Inline Python => <<END;
import logging
from os import sys
_logger = logging.getLogger()
_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
_logger.addHandler(handler)

def fun():
    print("From print")
    logging.info("Inside fun")
END

trap { fun(); };
print Dumper($trap->stdout);
print Dumper($trap->stderr);


sub fun1 {
    print "From fun1";
}

trap {fun1();};
print "Trap stdout from perl subroutine call\n";
print Dumper($trap->stdout);
print Dumper($trap->stderr);
```

Output:

```
From print
Inside fun
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR1 = '';
Trap stdout from perl subroutine call
$VAR1 = 'From fun1'
$VAR1 = '';
```

The output of this program is printing "From print" and "Inside fun" on the screen , but `$trap->stderr` and `$trap->stdout` is printed as blank for `fun()`(python API called from perl)
But for `fun1()` subroutine which is defined in Perl code, `trap->stdout` is printed.

Can anyone please suggest how to get stdout/stderr using trap for perl-python interface?

Comment: Have you tried to see if the output from the inline python actually goes to the main programs output channels? It could be doing all sorts of stuff, like creating a subshell, using a different binary to execute python code. Just because you see it on-screen does not mean it goes to stdout, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default "capture strategy" only captures what's sent to the STDOUT and STDERR Perl file handles, but Python doesn't know anything about Perl file handles.

Replace

```perl
use Test::Trap;
```

with

```perl
use Test::Trap ':stdout(systemsafe):stderr(systemsafe)';
```

Output

```perl
$VAR1 = 'From print
';
$VAR1 = 'Inside fun
';
Trap stdout from perl subroutine call
$VAR1 = 'From fun1';
$VAR1 = '';
```